# Find the specific source file from file list

Tags: makefile

I have following makefile

```make
target: debug
debug:   $(BIN_DEBUG)/$(TARGET_NAME).lib

#BIN_DEBUG is the path of debug folder
#TARGET_NAME is the library name.

#Rule for .libs
$(BIN_DEBUG)/$(TARGET_NAME).lib:    $(DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST)
    $(LIB) /OUT:$@ $^

#DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST is the list of .obj files in BIN_DEBUG folder.

#Rule for obj files
$(DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST):$(BIN_DEBUG)/%.obj:%.cpp
    @cl /c /Z7 /W3 /Od /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /Fo$@ /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue $(CFLAGS) $^

#In the rule for each obj file, I want to pick the corresponding file for the obj file. I have file list in SOURCE_LIST.

#It shows how DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST is derived.
DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST1 = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.obj,$(SOURCE_LIST))
DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST2 = $(notdir $(DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST1))
DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST   = $(patsubst %, $(BIN_DEBUG)/%, $(DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST2))
```

I need help in Rule for obj files. How to pickup the exact file for the given obj file?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want to do with this file?

Comment: There are bunch of cpp files inside source folder (and each one may be in different sub-folder). I want to compile them into a `.lib`. Same is to be done on other OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by setting `VPATH` variable. Please find more about [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html).

```
SRC_DIR_LIST    = $(dir $(SOURCE_LIST))
VPATH           = $(sort $(SRC_DIR_LIST))
```

Comment: I strongly disagree that VPATH should be used for this. VPATH, if it should be used at all, should be used for finding libraries and headers, not source files. Note that kbuild (the Linux Kernel build system) uses exactly one VPATH statement and that is set to exactly 1 or 2 directories: the cwd and the path to an external build module, if you're building one. If VPATH is the answer, the problem is that you haven't included the path element in the object file names, e.g. foo.c instead of src/path/foo.c.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, general points first `make` is tricky beast and is very sensitive to whitespace.

Your `patsubst` command should not include a space after the comma. Now, in *this* case, it shouldn't make a difference, as all you'll do is add an extra space between items, but I can guarantee that if you don't stamp-out the habit, it will come back to bite you when you're doing a larger, more complex build...

The rule for your obj files is unnecessarily complex.

```
$(DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST):$(BIN_DEBUG)/%.obj:%.cpp
    @cl ... $^
```

A more simple pattern rule will do the job:

```
$(BIN_DEBUG)/%.obj: %.cpp
    @cl ... $<
```

This will means: *"whenever I need a `.obj` file under `$(BIN_DEBUG)`, look for the corresponding `.cpp` file relative to the current directory"*. Also note that I use `$<` and not `$^` for the compile line. This will ensure that only the `.cpp` file is passed to the compiler, which is useful if you wanted to add a Makefile or a header to the implicit rule.

Finally, the `DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST` should *probably* be:

```
DEBUG_OBJECT_LIST = $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BIN_DEBUG)/%.obj,$(SOURCE_LIST))
```

Filtering-out directories is much easier to do by *simply not adding them to the list in the first place*. This is easy, if you don't use wildcards (either `wildcard` or `*.*` constructs). Wildcards *seem* like a good idea; a convenience, but they actually create more problems than they solve (including directories, non-source files, files you don't *want* to compile at the moment) - just bite the bullet and add source files to your sources list manually.

**Edit:** Correct error wrt. static pattern rule. Correct typo.

Comment: The rule `A.o B.o: %.o: %.cpp` is valid, and says to only use this pattern for the files before the first colon. And `$^` expands to all the dependencies for a target. In other words, your criticism of the "malformed" rule is misdirected.

Comment: Okay, good to know, but even so, it's unnecessarily complex for the task at hand. I'm aware that `$^` expands to all pre-requisites - my point was you probably shouldn't be using it in a pattern rule, as it would prevent you from doing `%.o:%.c Makefile some_other_file_that_is_needed_but_shouldnt_be_fed_to_the_compiler`.